# How to remove line breaks from a file in Java?

Tags: java, string, newline, line-breaks

How can I replace all line breaks from a string in Java in such a way that will work on Windows and Linux (ie no OS specific problems of carriage return/line feed/new line etc.)?

I've tried (note readFileAsString is a function that reads a text file into a String):

```
String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt");
text.replace("\n", "");
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate all line breaks? Or you want to uniformize them to a standard solution?

Comment: Oh, if you want to delete all linefeeds, remove all \n AND all \r (because Windows linebreak is \r\n).

Comment: Hey, FYI if you can want to replace simultaneous muti-linebreaks with single line break then you can use

 `myString.trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "\n")`

Or replace with a single space

  `myString.trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", " ")`

Answer (score 516, accepted):

You need to set `text` to the results of `text.replace()`:

```
String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt");
text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

This is necessary because Strings are immutable -- calling `replace` doesn't change the original String, it returns a new one that's been changed.  If you don't assign the result to `text`, then that new String is lost and garbage collected.

As for getting the newline String for any environment -- that is available by calling `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: +1, correct. As to the reason: String is **immutable**. The `replace()` method **returns** the desired result. Also see the API docs: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29 *Edit:* ah you already edited that yourself in afterwards :)

Comment: Perhaps `text = text.replace("\r\n", " ").replace("\n", " ");` is a better solution: otherwise words will be "glued" to each other (without the single-space replacement).

Comment: Yeah, that's possible.  It all depends on what type of data you're trying to modify.  Sometimes (for data such as COBOL copybooks) you don't want there to be any spaces between the lines.

Comment: True, it all depends on what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: You could also use square brackets to match newlines properly for any OS: `.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "")`

Comment: As the question is asking for replacing ALL occurrences, the solution is rather `text = text.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");`

Comment: @basZero `replaceAll` takes in regex, `replace` takes in literal strings, both replace all occurences.

Comment: be careful creating a System dependency, it might be what you want but I had a unit test with a static String that was passing on local Windows machine but failing on Continuous Integration build machine (Linux)

Comment: When the input text is like this : C:\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder , we get the output as : C:SomeFolderAnotherFolder. Means, it removes the backslashes, although, it was not intended to do so.

Comment: You won't believe what [this fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73357183/issue-with-arrays-streambody-split-foreach/73362088#73362088)

Comment: I found it this useful to handle the ascii value combo for "\n" at times:

content.replace("\\" + (char)92 + (char)110, "replacement");

Answer (score 273):

As noted in other answers, your code is not working *primarily* because `String.replace(...)` does not change the target `String`.  (It can't - Java strings are immutable!)  What `replace` actually does is to create and return  a new `String` object with the characters changed as required.  But your code then throws away that `String` ...

---

Here are some possible solutions.  Which one is most correct depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

```
// #1
text = text.replace("\n", "");
```

Simply removes all the newline characters.  This does not cope with Windows or Mac line terminations.

```
// #2
text = text.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```

Removes all line terminators for the current platform.  This does not cope with the case where you are trying to process (for example) a UNIX file on Windows, or vice versa.

```
// #3
text = text.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
```

Removes all Windows, UNIX or Mac line terminators.  However, if the input file is text, this will concatenate words; e.g.

```
Goodbye cruel
world.
```

becomes

```
Goodbye cruelworld.
```

So you might actually want to do this:

```
// #4
text = text.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
```

which replaces each line terminator with a space<sup>1</sup>.  Since Java 8 you can also do this:

```
// #5
text = text.replaceAll("\\R", " ");
```

And if you want to replace multiple line terminator with one space:

```
// #6
text = text.replaceAll("\\R+", " ");
```

---

<sup>1 - Note there is a subtle difference between #3 and #4.  The sequence `\r\n` represents a single (Windows) line terminator, so we need to be careful not to replace it with two spaces.</sup>

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT answer. Kudos for the Java 8 examples. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me... btw can u explain text = text.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");

Comment: Option 4: A \r will normally not be alone. If there is a \r there is a \n.

Comment: @Parthan_akon It's a regex. | means or. It will replace the first block that matches. So if there is \r\n, it will be replaced with one space. If there is a \r but no \n or the other way around, it will also be one space. He does it this way to prevent replacing \r and \n by a space and ending up with 2 spaces.

Comment: @Veda - Prior to MacOS 9, a `\r` without an `\n` was the line separator; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.  And on other old systems.

Answer (score 41):

[This function](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#normalizeSpace-java.lang.String-) normalizes down all whitespace, including line breaks, to single spaces.  Not exactly what the original question asked for, but likely to do exactly what is needed in many cases:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

final String cleansedString = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(rawString);
```

Answer (score 26):

If you want to remove only line terminators that are valid on the current OS, you could do this:

```
text = text.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```

If you want to make sure you remove any line separators, you can do it like this:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
```

Or, slightly more verbose, but less regexy:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\r", "").replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Comment: To avoid gluing word together (as discussed in comments to Kaleb's answer) the regex approach could be modified to `text.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)+", " ")` and (assuming greedy is default in Java?) you will have a solution with just *one* space for each sequence of new line chars.

Answer (score 14):

This would be efficient I guess

```
String s;
s = "try this\n try me.";
s.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "")
```

Comment: Make sure you have the exact same code, rather than losing the "\n" chars while pasting. Because it should work. Maybe it's because I forgot the last semicolon (;) at the end.

Answer (score 14):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
```

Worked perfectly for me after searching a lot, having failed with every other line.

Comment: I was trying to do it individually, not sure why it was not working, this one works like charm.

Answer (score 7):

Linebreaks are not the same under windows/linux/mac. You should use [System.getProperties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) with the attribute line.separator.

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin, and also since Java 11, `String` has `lines()` method, which returns list of lines in the multi-line string.
You can get all the lines and then merge them into a single string.

With Kotlin it will be as simple as

```
str.lines().joinToString("")
```

Comment: This is not at all useful for what was asked.

Comment: The question states: "replace all line breaks from a string" - and the solution does exactly that, in a simple, clean and reliable way.

Comment: They asked almost 12 years ago about Java - your answer about Kotlin is not of any use

Comment: My answer contains information about a Java method: `...since Java 11, String has lines() method...`. Kotlin example is a bonus.

Comment: I don't know about Kotlin and haven't done Java recently. If it's the case that you aren't providing a complete solution for Java but you are for Kotlin, then I couldn't say you've provided a full answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: Well, the question was asked more than 10 years ago. Welcome to the year 2022, absolute majority of professional Java developers heard about Kotlin and a lot of them are using Kotlin now. So this answer is relevant for a lot of people.

Answer (score 4):

```
String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt").replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Even though the definition of trim() in oracle website is 
"Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted."

the documentation omits to say that new line characters (leading and trailing) will also be removed.

In short
`String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt").trim();` will also work for you.
 (Checked with Java 6)

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt").replace("\n","");
```

.replace returns a new string, strings in Java are Immutable.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read your file with a `BufferedReader`. This class can break input into individual lines, which you can assemble at will. The way `BufferedReader` operates recognizes line ending conventions of the Linux, Windows and MacOS worlds automatically, regardless of the current platform.

Hence:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader("textfile.txt"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (;;) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(' ');   // SEE BELOW
}
String text = sb.toString();
```

Note that `readLine()` does not include the line terminator in the returned string. The code above appends a space to avoid gluing together the last word of a line and the first word of the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd that (Apache) [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) wasn't covered here yet.

you can remove all newlines (or any other occurences of a substring for that matter) from a string using the `.replace` method

```
StringUtils.replace(myString, "\n", "");
```

This line will replace all newlines with the empty string.

because newline is technically a character you can optionally use the `.replaceChars` method that will replace characters

```
StringUtils.replaceChars(myString, '\n', '');
```

Comment: `StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(myString, new String[]{"\n", "\t"}, new String[]{StringUtils.Empty, StringUtils.Empty});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons IOUtils to iterate through the line and append each line to StringBuilder. And don't forget to close the InputStream

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
LineIterator lt=IOUtils.lineIterator(fin, "utf-8");
while(lt.hasNext())
{
  sb.append(lt.nextLine());
}
String text = sb.toString();
IOUtils.closeQuitely(fin);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI if you can want to replace simultaneous muti-linebreaks with single line break then you can use

```
myString.trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "\n")
```

Or replace with a single space

```
myString.trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic methods to replace any char with any char.

```
public static void removeWithAnyChar(String str, char replceChar,
        char replaceWith) {
    char chrs[] = str.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < chrs.length) {

        if (chrs[i] == replceChar) {
            chrs[i] = replaceWith;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#chopNewline

Comment: -1 because [Deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#chopNewline(java.lang.String)) and only removes at the end of the string.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing this:

```
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\n", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\t", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\\n", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\\t", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\r", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\\r", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\r\n", "");
 textValue= textValue.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
```

Comment: if you replace `\n` there is no `\r\n` anymore
if you replace \n and there is an \\n it will be replaced so only the \ will remain.