# Replace new line/return with space using regex

Tags: java, regex

Pretty basic question for someone who knows.

Instead of getting from

```
"This is my text. 

And here is a new line"
```

To:

```
"This is my text. And here is a new line"
```

I get:

```
"This is my text.And here is a new line.
```

Any idea why?

```
L.replaceAll("[\\\t|\\\n|\\\r]","\\\s");
```

I think I found the culprit.

On the next line I do the following:

```
L.replaceAll( "[^a-zA-Z0-9|^!|^?|^.|^\\s]", "");
```

And this seems to be causing my issue.

Any idea why?

I am obviously trying to do the following: remove all non-chars, and remove all new lines.

Comment: Could you just do `L.replaceAll("[\\\t|\\\n|\\\r]"," ");`?

Comment: i tried and this appears to not work.

Answer (score 73):

`\s` is a shortcut for whitespace characters in regex. It has no meaning in a string. ==> You can't use it in your replacement string. There you need to put exactly the character(s) that you want to insert. If this is a space just use `" "` as replacement.

The other thing is: Why do you use 3 backslashes as escape sequence? Two are enough in Java. And you don't need a `|` (alternation operator) in a character class.

```
L.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]+"," ");
```

**Remark**

`L` is not changed. If you want to have a result you need to do

```
String result =     L.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]+"," ");
```

Test code:

```
String in = "This is my text.\n\nAnd here is a new line";
System.out.println(in);

String out = in.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]+"," ");
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: `L.replaceAll("[\\t|\\n|\\r]"," ");` also appears to not work though.

Comment: You might want to add a `+` after the character class, so you only get one space for each sequence of whitespace characters.

Comment: @jasonm I updated my solution. The changed string is **returned**, `L` is not changed. Is this your problem?

Comment: `        //How to remove all new and reutnrs
        String _L = L.replaceAll("[\\r?\\n|\\t]+"," ");

        //Normalize for all noncharss
        _L = _L.replaceAll( "[^a-zA-Z0-9|^!|^?|^.|^\\s]", "");

        //Normalize for the sentences
        _L = _L.replaceAll("[?|!]", ".");`

Comment: the above are the three lines of code i am using the clean the results.

Comment: @jasonm, I think you need to clarify your question (within your question, not as comment) and explain what you want to achieve, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 18):

The new line separator is different for different OS-es - '\r\n' for Windows and '\n' for Linux.

To be safe, you can use regex pattern **\R - the linebreak matcher introduced with Java 8**:

```
String inlinedText = text.replaceAll("\\R", " ");
```

Comment: Nice! Although to replace linebreak and spurious whitespace introduced by indentation? \R[\s]{2,} ?

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
L.replaceAll("(\\t|\\r?\\n)+", " ");
```

Depending on the system a linefeed is either `\r\n` or just `\n`.

Comment: This is wrong. `?` means a literal question mark in a character class (just as `|` is a literal here too). And four backslashes are overkill, even for Java. EDIT: But that's @adarshr's fault for not taking out the extra backslashes when reformatting the answer :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realise that. Glad it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative answer.  I was trying to solve a similar problem - replacing all OS' newlines with my host's standard newline, and this approach can be adapted for that problem - here's the regex:

"(\\r?\\n)+"

Comment: @Keppli I extended your way by `|\\n`, so no matter which kind of linefeed does exists.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is good altough I would replace it with the empty string

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[\t\n\r]", "");
```

You expect a space between "text." and "And" right?

I get that space when I try the regex by copying your sample

```
"This is my text. "
```

So all is well here. Maybe if you just replace it with the empty string it will work. I don't know why you replace it with \s. And the alternation | is not necessary in a character class.

Comment: I'm not doing jave but is it realy necessary to put an extra escape characters like \\t ? Isn't \t enough?

Comment: I think for `\t`, `\r` and `\n` you will get away with a single backslash. The regex engine will then not be given the string `\n` (which it would internally interpret as a newline character) but the newline character directly (0x0A, I think). But since all other backslashes in regexes do need to be doubled (`\s` or `\b` for example), it's convention to always use double backslashes.

Comment: @jasonm Can you save your file so we can download it? That will certainly allow us to diagnose what's going on

Comment: ...and again, the `|` does not belong there.  There's no need to specify OR in a character class, so `|` just matches a literal `|`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Of course, alternation is not necessary in a char class

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java).

```
String newString = string.replaceAll("\n", " ");
```

Although, as you have a double line, you will get a double space. I guess you could then do another replace all to replace double spaces with a single one.

If that doesn't work try doing:

```
string.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");
```

If I create lines in "string" by using "\n" I had to use "\n" in the regex. If I used System.getProperty() I had to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You May use first split and rejoin it using white space.
it will work sure.

```
String[] Larray = L.split("[\\n]+");
L = "";
for(int i = 0; i<Larray.lengh; i++){
   L = L+" "+Larray[i];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of space, tab and newline:

```
data = data.replaceAll("[ \t\n\r]*", " ");
```