# Substituting an element with whitespace. ( Perl Regex )

Tags: regex, perl, special-characters, whitespace

I am trying to substitute any `\n\` character with whitespace, but somehow `\s` isn't recognised as a whitespace substitution character.

`$match_to_array =~ s/\n/\s/;`

Comment: Similar question/answer (Java): [Replace new line/return with space using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11049108/626273)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` is a whole class of characters.  [It can mean , `\t`, `\r`, `\n`, or `\f`.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) You have to tell Perl which one to use.  For example, space:

```
$match_to_array =~ s/\n/ /
                       ^^^
```

Or tab:

```
$match_to_array =~ s/\n/\t/
                       ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know whitespace could mean more than just a 'space'. Cheers.

Comment: `\s` is only a regex character class that matches tab, linefeed, formfeed, carriage-return and space. In a double-quoted string it just means `s`, and the replacement part of a substitution is just a double-quoted string.