# Replacing newline after a pattern in unix

Tags: regex, unix, pattern-matching

I want to replace a newline with space after a pattern. 
For example my text is: 
1.
good movie 
(2006) 
This is a world class movie for music.
 Dir: 
abc 
 With: 
lan 
, 
cer 
, 
cro 
Comedy 
 | 
Drama 
 | 
Family 
 | 
Musical 
 | 
Romance 
120 mins.

53,097
I want above text to become something like this 
1. good movie (2006) 
 This is a wold class movie fo music. 
 Dir: abc 
 With: lan, cer, cro 
 comedy | Drama | Family | Musical | Romance 
 120 mins

Comment: so your just trying to remove the line breaks ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048973/replace-new-line-return-with-space-using-regex

Comment: First remove all the new lines, than do a regex replace on capitol letters or numbers followed by a . with themselves and a preceding newline.

Comment: What is the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

After the question update, the requirements for the solution changed:

```
cat test.txt | tr '\n' ' '  | perl -ne 's/(?<!\|) ([A-Z])/\n\1/g; print' | sed 's/ ,/,/g' | sed 's/ \([0-9]\+\)/\n\1/g'; echo
```

output:

```
1. good movie (2006)
This is a world class movie for music.
Dir: abc
With: lan, cer, cro
Comedy | Drama | Family | Musical | Romance
120 mins.
```

Explanation:

- First I replace all newline characters using `tr`.
- Second I replace    every capital letter by a preceding newline and
  itself **unless** it    is preceeded by a pipe "| "symbol.
- The third one corrects the comma spacings.
- The last moves the duration declaration to a new line

The `echo` at the very end is to append a 'newline' to the output.

---

**Deprecated:**
Building on kpie's comment, I suggest you the following solution:

```
cat test.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\n\1/g'
```

I pasted your input into test.txt.
The first `sed` replacement is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1863086
The second one replaces every captial letter by a preceding newline and itself.

EDIT:
Another possibility using `tr`:

```
cat test.txt | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\n\1/g'; echo
```

Comment: This works fine on my ubuntu, but on other machine, it shows as 'Label too long: :a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'

Comment: what kind of 'other machine'? I tested it on Fedora, Ubuntu and CentOS. Nevertheless, I edited my answer and added another possibility using `tr` instead of `sed`

Comment: well, it is hard to find a working answer when you are changing the requirements.. check the updated answer.

Comment: What if there is a space before | and after this also