# \n and \\s+ not working in Java

Tags: java, replace, bluej

So I'm an IB student and I'm taking Comp. Sci. we need to create a code to solve a problem, as i was writing my Java code I found the `String.replaceAll();` that is helpful in writing my code. I had to remove any white spaces, and any new lines, so I found `\\s+` and `\\n`. So as I enter the code `String.replaceAll("\\s+","");` it didn't work, same with `String.replaceAll("\\n","");`. I have tried removing the " " but BlueJ, sends an error saying that `\` is an illegal character. I checked if maybe the `String.replaceAll();` doesn't works but it does work, so I came to a conclusion that something is wrong with `\\s+` and `\\n`.

I have found an alternative in removing white spaces `String.replaceAll(" ","");`, but I still need a way to remove new lines.

Here is a part of the code

```
String name = InputString("Enter name: ");
String name1 = name.replaceAll("\\s+","");
   output(name1); // the output function is located in the IBIO which is provided because I'm and IB student
```

Alright so someone had given me a code that will remove all of the new lines `\\n`, but if people can give me the reason why my `\\s+` not working that would be helpful.

Comment: I assume you're referring to Java, and *not* JavaScript...

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java

It explains what you need to do

Comment: could you please give your input value as well

Answer (score 4):

What does "it doesn't work" mean?

One thing regarding this that people often forget is that class `String` is immutable. That means that if you call a method like `replace()` on a `String`, the original string is **not** changed; instead, the method returns a new string.

```
String s = "Hello World";

// Does not change the original string!
s.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 

// Use this instead to assign s to the new string
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: I have entered a part of the code and you can see I declared the things up there. And someone had just now entered '.replaceAll("(?s)\\s+", "");' which works fine for new line.

Answer (score 3):

A possible reason which really stumps people why `\\s` does not work is if character code 0xa0 (non-breaking space) is present instead of a normal space.  The method `replaceAll` does not catch 0xa0 with a `\\s` regex.  Instead, you would have to do something like:

```
String name1 = name.replaceAll("\\u00a0","");
```

to replace non-breaking spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
System.out.println("Multiline \r\n String".replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
```

prints

```
MultilineString
```

Therefore I suggest you post the exact string literal you are experiencing problems with, with the exact output produced.

Comment: The thing is it doesn't output anything, it uses the new string to create a text file. And if I do output(); or System.out.println(); it would give the same result other then that fact that System.out.println(); will give it out in a text file.

Comment: So your problem lies elsewhere entirely. `output` is not a standard Java function and neither is `InputString`. Do you even know for sure what is the string you are trying to process?

Comment: Yes you are right, as IB students we get a code called the IBIO which does the output function and other functions as well, sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

to remove newline from String

```
String s = "Enter name :\n Your name ";
        s = s.replaceAll("\n", "");
```