# How do I replace "\n" with "\r\n" in groovy?

Tags: java, string, groovy

My groovy program creates a csv that is has \n for new line. But the customer wants \r\n as they run windows.

I understand that this question is answered a tonne of time on SO including here [How to remove line breaks from a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java)

This script here does not replace \n with \r\n. The \n just stays on

```
    newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++) {
        InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
        Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        outData = new StringBuffer();
        lineNum = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line.replace(newline, "\r\n")
            outData.append(line);


        }
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        dataContext.storeStream(is, props);
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, you should always close() your streams in a finally { ... } block.

Comment: If you want to convert a file from a second command use something like dos2unix.
But if you want to generate the file with the proper line separator you can simply set a proper line separator in the script that generates the file itself simply use:

System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n")

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the file a line at the time by using readLine - this already removes the line ending for you.

What you need to do is read the lines one at a time as you do now - then append \r\n in between each line, not replace.

```
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        outData.append(line);
        outData.append("\r\n");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Now I only have  \n at the end of each line.
I write the file into the windows file system as a .csv and open it with SublimeText. Here I try to search for '\r\n' and it returns nothing.