# Find \n in Edit Text android

Tags: java, android, character

I want to find `\n` in Edit Text then do something;
I don't want to give user error when he use enter in edit text 
For example in my app nobody allows to  write this sentence 
sentence: `"Hello \n world"`

I used this code, it worked for characters but didn't work for `\n`
code:

```
private boolean findn(String t){
    for (int i=0;i<t.length();i++){
        if (t.charAt(i)=='\n'){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem with change digits in xml

```
        android:digits="@string/myAlphaNumeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) method to determine whether a String contains a given character sequence, like so:

```
return t.contains("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks
I use contain method like it
et.gettext.ToString.contains"/n";
but it doesn't work