# How to prevent CR/LF?

Tags: java, html, string, line-breaks, pdfbox

I am reading from a pdf using `pdfbox` and apparently, at least on a Windows-based framework, for the line break it uses a unicode as such `&#13;&#10`.

My question is that how can I prevent this line breaking character to be concatenated to the string in below code?

```
tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(Text,"\\.");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String x= tokenizer.nextToken();
    flag=0;
    for(final String s :x.split(" ")) {
       if(flag==1)
          break;
       if(Keyword.toLowerCase().equals(s.toLowerCase()) && !"".equals(s)) {
          sum+=x+"."; //here need first to check for "&#13;&#10"
                      // before concatenating the String "x" to String "sum"
          flag=1;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: !"".equals(s) -> s.isEmpty() ?! Use StringBuilder instead of sum+=x+".";

Comment: Try `x.trim()` to remove whitespaces at start and end, then check `x.isEmpty()`

Comment: @fafl no use for `.trim()`.

Comment: @Tokazio how am I supposed to use it? can you give a short example?

Comment: maybe a simple replace("\r\n",""); ?

Comment: StringBuilder sum = new StringBuilder(); before loop then sum.append(x).append("."); and end with sum.toString()

Comment: @Tokazio nope, still same thing happens.

Comment: Found text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""); in another SO post. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: You might want to consider using `Keyword.equalsIgnoreCase(s)` instead of `Keyword.toLowerCase().equals(s.toLowerCase())`.  And if `Keyword` is not `""`, then the `&& !"".equals(s)` is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should discard the line separators when you split; e.g.

```
for (final String s : x.split("\\s+")) {
```

That is making the word separator one or more whitespace characters.

(Using `trim()` won't work in all cases.  Suppose that `x` contains `"word\r\nword"`.  You won't split between the two words, and `s` will be `"word\r\nword"` at some point.  Then `s.trim()` won't remove the line break characters because they are not at the ends of the string.)

---

**UPDATE**

I just spotted that you are actually appending `x` not `s`.  So you also need to do something like this:

```
sum += x.replaceAll("\\s+", " ") + "."
```

That does a bit more than you asked for.  It replaces each whitespace sequence with a single space.

---

By the way, your code would be simpler and more efficient if you used a `break` to get out of the loop rather than messing around with a flag.  (And Java has a `boolean` type ... for heavens sake!)

```
   if (Keyword.toLowerCase().equals(s.toLowerCase()) && !"".equals(s)) {
       sum += ....
       break;
   }
```

Comment: unfortunately, it still includes the line breaking feed.

Comment: @AJNeufeld - That won't help.  `\r` and `\n` are members of the `\s` character class.

Comment: didnt I use a break? i know Java has a Boolean type so I regarded an integer of  value`1` as true and `0` for false. Is that wrong? I mean, I used an integer as a Boolean for value of 1 as true and 0 for false just like what a Boolean dose.  I know `int` wastes a lot of memory space but this is not a commercial product so I guess that will not harm anything? if this is some serious mistake, you might point it out to me now.

Comment: Re `break`:  yes you did ... but not in the right place.  Re: the use of `boolean` instead of `int`: use it for clarity, not efficiency.  The fact it is not commercial is beside the point.  The point is that other people (like us) need to read your code.

Comment: Alright. But can you tell me where the right way for using break is? I mean in the context of my code.

Comment: Oh my, I understood now, I just made some unnecessary coding. That is what happens when you are not a perfect programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be adding `x` here?

```
if(Keyword.toLowerCase().equals(s.toLowerCase()) && !"".equals(s)) {
    sum+=x+"."; //here need first to check for "&#13;&#10"
                // before concatenating the String "x" to String "sum"
    flag=1;
}
```

Don't you want `s`?

```
    sum += s + ".";
```

---

**UPDATE**

Oh, I see.  So what you really want is something more like:

```
tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(Text,"\\.");
Pattern KEYWORD = Pattern.compile("\\b"+Keyword+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sum);
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String x = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if (KEYWORD.matcher(x).find()) {
        sb.append(x.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")).append('.');
    }
}
sum = sb.toString();
```

(Assuming Keyword starts and ends with letters, and doesn't itself contain any RegEx codes)

Comment: no, I am sure I want `x` because `s` is a token of it and when the `s` is equal to a keyword, i want to save the whole `x` and not the `s` cause that is useless.

Comment: Well, `x.split(...)` does not modify `x`, so any new line characters in `x` will still be in it.  You'll need to use a solution like @Stephen has already posted.