# Remove line breaks within double quotes in Java

Tags: java

My data is in the below format

```
1,"Hello,
World"
2,"HI,Hello"
```

I need to remove the line breaks Within the double quotes from Java.
The data will look like :-

```
1,"Hello, World"
2,"HI,Hello"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks from a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2163056/2893693

Comment: @GurwinderSingh This is NOT a duplicate of the Q and A suggested in these comments. This specifically asks how to only remove line breaks *within quotes*. This is actually harder than it seems. (For instance, there may be escaped quotes inside a quoted part.)

Comment: If your file is in fact a CSV file, then have a look for a CSV reader API for Java. There are several you can download, but I don't know which ones are good.

Answer (score 1):

You just can use the String method replace():
`str.replace("\"[\s\S]*\n[\s\S]*\""", "")`

Comment: Did I help you?

Comment: So far, this answer is actually the closest one to what the OP requires.