# Read CSV File with conditional linebreaks

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file in my loading program.

As a CSV file, its data format is thus:

```
1,dataA,dataB,"String Data",dataD
2,dataA,dataB,"String Data",dataD
3,dataA,dataB,"String Data",dataD
```

Previously, I was using `Files.newBufferedReader` to read my file line by line, which works. But it has come to my attention that some data can look like this:

```
1,dataA,dataB,"String Data",dataD
2,dataA,dataB,"String 
Data",dataD
3,dataA,dataB,"String 

Data",dataD
```

In some of my string data, there are potential line breaks.

I thought of removing the line breaks [as per this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163045/how-to-remove-line-breaks-from-a-file-in-java), but that will affect the individual entries as well. And I don't think its recommended to manually remove the line breaks from the source data itself.

Is there any way to split so that I can still read it entry-by-entry but retain the line breaks **only in the string data which is encapsulated by quotation ("") marks**?

### Edit

As per suggestion, I've been reading up on something called OpenCSV.

No, I am still getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to the spacing.

It's still reading

```
3,dataA,dataB,"String 

Data",dataD
```

for example as 3 lines as opposed to 1.

### Edit 2

I stand corrected. OpenCSV worked; the error was because I was still calling the older method.

Comment: Use a proper CSV API

Comment: If you're limited on what you can do with regards to dependencies, just loop through reading bytes, skipping any `\n` that occur within quotes.   But in general, it would be wise to follow g00se.

Comment: @g00se Like what? Any suggestions on where I can start? Also, this is meant to be loaded to a local DB.

Comment: Start by googling "Java CSV library".  Requests to find or recommend libraries, etc are off-topic.

Comment: Apache commons is often used for csv